# Expand card component and center it after hiding other components in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I created a button that hides other components on the page except one and then the one that is left is expanded and then it should be moved to the center.
However somehow the component is not aligning itself in the center after clicking on the button.

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/pokepim/pen/WNbBqjP) with the current behaviour.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    lorem: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel at clita quando. Te sit oratio vituperatoribus, nam ad ipsum posidonium mediocritatem, explicari dissentiunt cu mea. Repudiare disputationi vim in, mollis iriure nec cu, alienum argumentum ius ad. Pri eu justo aeque torquatos.`,
    show1: true,
    show2: true,
    show3: true,
    show4: true,
    show5: true,
    expand1:true
    
  }),
  methods: {
    hideothers() {
        this.show2=!this.show2,
        this.show3=!this.show3,
        this.show4=!this.show4,
        this.show5=!this.show5,
        this.expand1=!this.expand1
                 }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid grid-list-sm>
      <v-layout row wrap>
<!-- top starts here-->
        <v-flex d-flex xs12 sm4 child-flex>
          <v-card color="orange lighten-2" tile flat v-show="show1"> 
            <v-card-text>Card 1</v-card-text>
             <v-btn flat  @click="hideothers()">Expand</v-btn>
             <v-card-text>
                  <v-expand-transition>
                    <div v-show="expand1">This is a short paragraph</div>
                  </v-expand-transition>
                  <v-expand-transition>
                    <div v-show="!expand1">
                      <p>A looooong</p>
                      <p>paragraph</p>
                    </div>
                  </v-expand-transition>
                </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
        
         <v-flex d-flex xs12 sm4 child-flex>
           <v-fade-transition>
             
           
          <v-card color="orange lighten-2" tile flat v-show="show2">
            <v-card-text>
            <v-layout row wrap>
              <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
               <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
               <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
               <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
               <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
               <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
             </v-fade-transition>
        </v-flex>

        <v-flex d-flex xs12 sm4>
          <v-card color="red lighten-2" dark tile flat v-show="show3">
            <v-card-text>{{ lorem.slice(0, 100) }}</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
  <!-- TOP part ends here-->     
        
         <v-flex d-flex xs12 sm4 child-flex>
          <v-card color="purple lighten-1" tile flat v-show="show4">
            <v-card-text>{{lorem}}</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12 sm4 child-flex v-show="show5">
          <v-card color="green lighten-2" tile flat>
            <v-card-text>{{lorem}}</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
        
       
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: as I shown in my answer below you cannot center element in flex container if other elements'childs just hidden. You have to replace v-show with v-if and place them into v-flex. Also to center content in the flex container you need to turn on justify-center prop of the v-layout

Comment: If you expand card component then you don't need to center it horizontally. Either you wish to expand it or to center it with 1/3 width of its container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically change the following line

```
<v-flex xs12 sm4 child-flex v-show="show2" :class="{ 'd-flex': show2 }">
```

Apply d-flex class only when its shown and also hide this div when the parameter is false

Also add `justify-content: center` CSS to the wrapper of all the 5 divs

See the updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/nandita121189/pen/oNgKXrX)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    lorem: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mel at clita quando. Te sit oratio vituperatoribus, nam ad ipsum posidonium mediocritatem, explicari dissentiunt cu mea. Repudiare disputationi vim in, mollis iriure nec cu, alienum argumentum ius ad. Pri eu justo aeque torquatos.`,
    show1: true,
    show2: true,
    show3: true,
    show4: true,
    show5: true,
    expand1: true

  }),
  methods: {
    hideothers() {
      this.show2 = !this.show2,
        this.show3 = !this.show3,
        this.show4 = !this.show4,
        this.show5 = !this.show5,
        this.expand1 = !this.expand1
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.custom-class {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.22/dist/vuetify.min.css">

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid grid-list-sm>
      <v-layout row wrap :class="{ 'custom-class': !show2 }">
<!-- top starts here-->
        <v-flex d-flex xs12 sm4 child-flex v-show="show1">
          <v-card color="orange lighten-2" tile flat > 
            <v-card-text>Card 1</v-card-text>
             <v-btn flat  @click="hideothers()">Expand</v-btn>
             <v-card-text>
                  <v-expand-transition>
                    <div v-show="expand1">This is a short paragraph</div>
                  </v-expand-transition>
                  <v-expand-transition>
                    <div v-show="!expand1">
                      <p>A looooong</p>
                      <p>paragraph</p>
                    </div>
                  </v-expand-transition>
                </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
        
         <v-flex xs12 sm4 child-flex v-show="show2" :class="{ 'd-flex': show2 }">
           <v-fade-transition>
             
           
          <v-card color="orange lighten-2" tile flat  v-show="show2">
            <v-card-text>
            <v-layout row wrap>
              <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
               <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
               <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
               <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
               <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
               <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
             </v-fade-transition>
        </v-flex>

        <v-flex xs12 sm4 v-show="show3" :class="{ 'd-flex': show3 }">
          <v-card color="red lighten-2" dark tile flat  v-show="show3">
            <v-card-text>{{ lorem.slice(0, 100) }}</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
  <!-- TOP part ends here-->     
        
         <v-flex xs12 sm4 child-flex v-show="show4" :class="{ 'd-flex': show4 }">
          <v-card color="purple lighten-1" tile flat v-show="show4">
            <v-card-text>{{lorem}}</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12 sm4 child-flex v-show="show5"  :class="{ 'd-flex': show2 }">
          <v-card color="green lighten-2" tile flat>
            <v-card-text>{{lorem}}</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
       
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I tried to do. I wonder if the transition can be also applied to the justify-content

Answer (score 0):

Try ou this :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid grid-list-sm>
      <v-layout row wrap :justify-center="!expand1">
<!-- top starts here-->
        <v-flex d-flex xs12 sm4 child-flex>
          <v-card color="orange lighten-2" tile flat v-show="show1"> 
            <v-card-text>Card 1</v-card-text>
             <v-btn flat  @click="hideothers()">Expand</v-btn>
             <v-card-text>
                  <v-expand-transition>
                    <div v-show="expand1">This is a short paragraph</div>
                  </v-expand-transition>
                  <v-expand-transition>
                    <div v-show="!expand1">
                      <p>A looooong</p>
                      <p>paragraph</p>
                    </div>
                  </v-expand-transition>
                </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>

         <v-flex d-flex xs12 sm4 child-flex v-if="show2">
           <v-fade-transition>


          <v-card color="orange lighten-2" tile flat>
            <v-card-text>
            <v-layout row wrap>
              <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
              <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
               <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
               <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
               <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
               <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
               <v-flex sm6>
                 Card1
              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
             </v-fade-transition>
        </v-flex>

        <v-flex d-flex xs12 sm4 v-if="show3">
          <v-card color="red lighten-2" dark tile flat>
            <v-card-text>{{ lorem.slice(0, 100) }}</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
  <!-- TOP part ends here-->     

         <v-flex d-flex xs12 sm4 child-flex v-if="show4">
          <v-card color="purple lighten-1" tile flat>
            <v-card-text>{{lorem}}</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12 sm4 child-flex v-show="show5">
          <v-card color="green lighten-2" tile flat>
            <v-card-text>{{lorem}}</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>


      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the required widths md4 and md12 to whether it is expanded or not. 
Like this: `<v-flex d-flex xs12 :sm4="expand1" :sm12="!expand1" child-flex>`

[see the pen](https://codepen.io/kovacstelod/pen/LYEwVoY)

Comment: Well the thing is that it will take whole width of the container and that is not what I want